# Some hardware for multiple SIM cards SMS sending

Tags: usb

I need some hardware for multiple SIM cards SMS sending. Preferably 200 sim cards. I would use Linux and some development boards like Raspberry pi etc. I have used raspberry with a USB dongle. Please advice solutions for multiple sim cards.

Comment: If you can't get a good answer here, it may be worth trying our [Raspberry Pi affiliate site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour). I'm not familiar with their site so it may be worth checking out what [is](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [isn't](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on topic for their site to minimize chance of closure.

Comment: Just curious - why would someone need 200 sim cards in a single, cheap, small form factor system? Also recommendation type questions are pretty unique to here and SR.SE so reasking the same question there may not be a good idea.

Comment: We just need to receive and send many texts. So that's why.

Comment: Also I have worked with VOIP GSM gateways connected to a motherboard, but they are too expensive in this case.

Comment: Would something like this suffice: https://www.amazon.com/ILS-Bluetooth-SIM800C-Computer-Control/dp/B07FCG4QZV and then you could attach multiple to one PC or use a USB Hub and get up to 127 or so connected I think which is the USB limit. Also, why would one SIM not be able to handle the multiple send and receive of SMS messages for you??